# The Ask Question link is wrapped

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

Check out the screen shot:

[image]

(Apparently Firefox isn't liking House Whiteboard...)

Comment: Almost recursive...

Comment: I'm using chrome 8 and I have the same problem as well

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this on my netbook as well which is running Firefox 3.6.8 with a screen resolution of 1024x600. However, preforming a hard refresh seems to do the trick when it happens so it might be an issue with the style sheets not getting downloaded correctly (i.e. my problem, not yours).

Answer (score 2):

I have updated the css, so in case you can't load the custom font, the fall back font won't be wrapped to 2 lines. The fix will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Hi Jin, at home with Vista & FF3.6.13, it works, so a bit of a mystery... I'll see Monday...

Answer (score 1):

what Browser / OS? Can't repro in Firefox current version (3.6.13) / Windows 7 64-bit:

[image]

Comment: 3.6.13, XP (in French, FWIW), and I've even got the House Whiteboard font on my computer... (maybe that's the problem?)

Comment: Same machine Chrome 8.0.552.224 ok. IE 8 too. I'll try from home when I get back.

Comment: @benjol I expect that corporate proxies are blocking the font file. The other question asked about this, that we can't repro either, seems to imply that. http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/688/styling-problems-with-new-theme-and-ie8

Comment: @Jeff, any way I can help you prove that/help us let it through?  (And that doesn't really match up with it working in Chrome and IE?)

Comment: @josh uh this does not use sifr. I have flash disabled. You might want to remove that comment.

Comment: @Jeff: I noticed a lag and assumed it was sIFR. Let me spin up FF3 and check, I'm currently using FF4.

Comment: @Jeff: There is a noticeable lag before the font changes and the menu bar aligns in FF3 & FF4.

Comment: @Josh: that has nothing to do with sIFR and everything to do with browsers loading fonts so as to be non-blocking. Programmers.SE uses [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/@font-face) to load the custom font.

Comment: @Mark: I understand that, however the issue isn't that the custom font isn't loading but rather the fallback font isn't styled correctly.

Comment: @Josh K You're right. Currently the fallback font wraps to second line. I'll put in a fix for this.